# How do i save an image to the gallery using an app i made?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have this **Xamarin Android App** (not Forms) that opens a camera and lets me take a photo and go with it or take a new one. After that, `ImageView` shows me the pic on the app using a bitmap. I could not save to gallery using bitmap(I don't know how to, or if there is an easier way). I need the app to get the last picture taken with the application (The why of needing it to be saved) and send it to a server on the click of a button (I need some help on that bit as well). And that's all I need to do.
Here are the code `MainActivity.cs`:

```
using Android.App;

using Android.Widget;

using Android.OS;

using Android.Content;

using Android.Provider;

using Android.Runtime;

using Android.Graphics;

namespace CameraApp

{

    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]

    public class MainActivity : Activity

    {

        ImageView imageView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)

        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            Button btnCamera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);

            imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);

            btnCamera.Click += BtnCamera_Click;

        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)

        {

            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

            imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

        private void BtnCamera_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at the Media Plugin.
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a demo about your needs.I add the camera and external storeage permission and store the image to gallery, here is running GIF.

[image]

There is code of running demo.I add the runtime permission(camera and WriteExternalStorage) request.and judge situations when users did not take photo, then return back the app.

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, ActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
{
    Button button1;
    ImageView imageView1;
    View layout;
    static readonly int REQUEST_CAMERA_WriteExternalStorage = 0;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        layout = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.sample_main_layout);
        button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        imageView1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        button1.Click += (o, e) =>
        {
            CheckPermission();
        };
    }


    public  void CheckPermission()
    {
        if ((ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) == (int)Permission.Granted)&& (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted))
        {
            // Camera and store permission has  been granted
            ShowCamera();
        }
        else
        {
            // Camera and store permission has not been granted
            RequestPermission();

        }


    }

    private void RequestPermission()
    {

        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, REQUEST_CAMERA_WriteExternalStorage);

    }


    //get result of persmissions
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_WriteExternalStorage)
        {


            if ( PermissionUtil.VerifyPermissions(grantResults))
            {
                // All required permissions have been granted, display Camera.

                ShowCamera();
            }
            else
            {
                // permissions did not grant, push up a snackbar to notificate USERS
                Snackbar.Make(layout, Resource.String.permissions_not_granted, Snackbar.LengthShort).Show();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void ShowCamera()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }


    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        //If user did not take a photeo , he will get result of bitmap, it is null
        try {
             bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("TakePhotoDemo1", e.Message);
            Toast.MakeText(this, "You did not take a photo", ToastLength.Short).Show();

        }

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(ContentResolver, bitmap, "screen", "shot");
            imageView1.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "You did not take a photo", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

    }

}
```

`PermissionUtil.cs` Check that all given permissions have been granted by verifying that each entry in the given array is of the value Permission.Granted.

```
   public abstract class PermissionUtil
{

    public static bool VerifyPermissions(Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        // At least one result must be checked.
        if (grantResults.Length < 1)
            return false;

        // Verify that each required permission has been granted, otherwise return false.
        foreach (Permission result in grantResults)
        {
            if (result != Permission.Granted)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

There is my code.

https://github.com/851265601/TakePhotoDemo1

The former code will add the image at the end of the gallery(`MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage`). If you want to modify the date so it appears at the beginning or any other metadata, see this link.
https://gist.github.com/samkirton/0242ba81d7ca00b475b9

Comment: Do you have any updates? If the reply help to you, please mark the reply as answer.

Comment: Leon Lu thanks so much. i understood now how to do it and i appreciate the code sample. But i have a question. You added contacts strings but i don't know what you are using them for. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the image through MediaStore

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(this, yourBitmap, yourTitle, yourDescription);
```

Note: You might wanna add the Write External Storage permission for this.